# I'd like to click anywhere (blank area) in a list view

Tags: android, listview

As a new android programmer I have my obligatory todo app running.  It is acceptable for Christmas shopping, but I'd really like to make the whole list-item row clickable.  Right now I have to tap the text.  The shorter the item the harder to hit.

My main activity extends ListActivity.  I use a subclass of ResourceCursorAdapter for the list itself.  My layout looks like this (thanks!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/todo_row"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBox android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/todo_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:checked="false"
        ></CheckBox>

<TextView android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/todo_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tapping anywhere in the row is the default behavior of a listView.  How are you setting up your onClick listeners?  You should use the [onItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html).

Comment: I overrode onListItemClick in my ListActivity.  I think that should be equivalent(?)

Comment: Yes, that should be. Did you try setting the CheckBox clickable=false?

Comment: I'm actually using the click.  If you touch the checkbox you can toggle the done-ness immediately, and touch the text to update/delete in a new view.  It works pretty well, I'd just like the touch for update to work to the right of the text.

Comment: Oh, you can't have both.  You can either have a clickable item within the listView, or you can have the entire row be clickable.  Maybe you can put something behind the TextView that takes up all of the space and is clickable.  However, keep in mind that lots of people have big fingers.  Forcing them to distinguish between a click on a tiny checkbox, and on the space next to it is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll call that an answer.  This is just my personal to-do.  It's too simple to offer, but does everything I need.  (It was funny when I was back on the iphone, looking for a good to-do.  It seemed the features needed to differentiate an app just clogged them up.)