# UITableView : click in blank area will not trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, select

When I am developing iOS8 Today Extension, I set a UITableViewController as the 
main view controller.And I met this problem:

When I init the UITableViewCell using initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the whole area of one cell can trigger didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
normally. However when set UITableViewCellStyle to UITableViewCellStyleValue1, 
UITableViewCellStyleValue2 or UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, I can only trigger 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath by click in detailTextLabel or imageView's area. Click in other blank 
areas will get no respond.

I've tried to set tableview's delegate to self, set detailTextLabel and imageView's 
setUserInteractionEnabled:false in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and all these do not work. Does 
anyone have any idea about this?

P.S. I am not using storyboard or xib file,just code.

I've found a same problem on Android:
[I'd like to click anywhere (blank area) in a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511137/id-like-to-click-anywhere-blank-area-in-a-list-view)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I encountered this myself while trying to display `UITableView` inside the `TodayView`. Although I don't know why is this happening, I found out that this only occurs when the `UITableViewCell` background is `clearColor`. If you set the background to some other color, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will be called. However, here's a quick workaround - put `UILabel` to stretch on whole area of the cell's `contentView` and then the delegate method will be called every time. Anyway, it seems like a bug.

Comment: Thanks, it did work. At last I added an almost transparent background color to fix this unelegantly. Should be an iOS bug because if I set bg color's alpha to 0.002 it works, but 0.001 does not work.